# how to solve git push fails with two-step authentication (linux)

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, authentication, github

I'm trying to push some edits from personal proyect to my repository and requires me my username and pass, i write them but the console show me something like:

```
fatal: authentication failed
```

I didn't make any mistake writing my username and pass, so I tried to figure out and I think this is for the two-step authentication that i have on my github account. Someone knows how to solve that?, I'll be glad.

Comment: If this is for github, the easiest method is to add an ssh key and use the ssh access methods instead of https. See [https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/]

Comment: Hey @NickStoughton, thanks for the suggestion, btw, your link do not work, but it's ok. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @NickStoughton mentioned in the comments, SSH is probably the best way to do this.

Here is the fixed version of his link: 
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: I saw some stuff about that (SSH), i tried but without success, now i'm gonna do it right, thanks for the link @tehp .